# how to extract nouns from a sentence by locating the previous words?

Tags: python

For example, there is a sentence "I have an apple an my friend have an apple, how many apples do me and my friend have together". I want to input the whole sentence into python, and let the python extract the noun right after "how many"(which is apples, I do not want the noun "friends" to be extracted as well). How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try something? did you look at `regex`?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. If you just want the word after 'how many' use a regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> s="I have an apple an my friend have an apple, how many apples do me and my friend have together"
>>> re.search(r'how many (\w+)', s).group(1)
'apples'
```

Or just use `.split` appropriately:

```
>>> s.split('how many ')[1].split()[0]
'apples'
```